# Apache 301 Redirect Add language prefix if not present

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.hemsida\.eu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.hemsida\.eu$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/testar\.se\/sv/$1" [R=301,L]
```

So this one will redirect all traffic from test.hemsida.eu to `https://testar.se/sv/$1`

But the problem is if test.hemsida.eu contains sv in the path, it redirects: `https://testar.se/sv/sv/test`

How can I get rid of one the sv, but still maintain it, if it isn't present in the URL?

Comment: Remove the **sv** from your rewrite rule's destination.

Comment: If I do, it won't redirect test.hemsida.eu to testar.se/sv

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question. You can use this pattern **^(?:sv)?(.*)$** so it matchs the sv as optional path but wont append it to target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this by tweaking your regex:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?test\.hemsida\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:sv/)?(.*)$ https://testar.se/sv/$1 [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

`(?:sv/)?` (optional match) at the start of pattern will make sure that you always capture whatever comes after `/sv/` or if there no `/sv/` then complete match.